# No view found for id 0x... (com.example.user.fragmentlistexample:id/container) for fragment ExampleItemFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.airpair.com/android/list-fragment-android-studio
and getting the error,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.fragmentlistexample/com.example.user.fragmentlistexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080002 (com.example.user.fragmentlistexample:id/container) for fragment ExampleItemFragment{2f05586b #1 id=0x7f080002}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
```

ExampleItemFragment.java:

```
package com.example.user.fragmentlistexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.user.fragmentlistexample.dummy.DummyContent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 * <p/>
 * Large screen devices (such as tablets) are supported by replacing the ListView
 * with a GridView.
 * <p/>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnFragmentInteractionListener}
 * interface.
 */
public class ExampleItemFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private List exampleListItemList;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * The fragment's ListView/GridView.
     */
    private AbsListView mListView;

    /**
     * The Adapter which will be used to populate the ListView/GridView with
     * Views.
     */
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    public static ExampleItemFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ExampleItemFragment fragment = new ExampleItemFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ExampleItemFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        exampleListItemList = new ArrayList();
        exampleListItemList.add(new ExampleListItem("Example 1"));
        exampleListItemList.add(new ExampleListItem("Example 2"));
        exampleListItemList.add(new ExampleListItem("Example 3"));
        mAdapter = new ExampleListAdapter(getActivity(), exampleListItemList);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example_item_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ExampleListItem item = (ExampleListItem)this.exampleListItemList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.getItemTitle() + " Clicked!"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * The default content for this Fragment has a TextView that is shown when
     * the list is empty. If you would like to change the text, call this method
     * to supply the text it should use.
     */
    public void setEmptyText(CharSequence emptyText) {
        View emptyView = mListView.getEmptyView();

        if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) emptyView).setText(emptyText);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.user.fragmentlistexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ExampleItemFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ExampleItemFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id){

    }
}
```

MainActivityFragment.java

```
package com.example.user.fragmentlistexample;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.user.fragmentlistexample.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

fragment_example_item_list.xml

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center" />
```

FragmentMain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` you are using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and then using

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ExampleItemFragment())
                .commit();
```

Here you are using `R.id.container` which is basically not present in your `activity_main.xml` but in `fragment_main.xml`. That's the reason it is showin `NullPointerException`.

If you want to access the container from the `MainActivity` then define the container inside `activity_main.xml`